# How to Display Enum value in Kendo grid By using Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

Everyone.My Question is How to display enum value into kendo grid colummn?

right now i passed as it is. but my requirement to reduce this code and use enum

```
 var levelType = function myfunction() {
            NA = 0,`enter code here`
            SpeechRecognition = 1,`enter code here`
            Transcriptionist = 2,
            Review = 3,
            SuperProof = 4,
            PreAudit = 5,
            Formatter = 6,
            PostAudit = 7,
            Customer = 8
        }
```

directly and provide enum type value in kendo grid. I am using angular function so please answer should be in angularjs. how can i reduce the template code and directly assign the value of enum to kendo grid .`enter code here`

Thanks

Comment: below is also my code .It was not a answer .editor box didn't contain it thats why i passed it as answer.please look at both code and provide me solution,

Answer (score 0):

but i want to reduce the code of template and kendo grid display the api value .i want to put a condtion that if 1 come from api then display a value from enum type corresponding 1.

```
columns: [
                       {
                           template: "<div class='mdi-device-access-time' id='red-clock'> </div> #=StatType#" + "<label>H</label>",
                           title   : "Type",
           width   : "50"
                       },
                       {
                           template: '#if(Level == "0"){#' +
                                     '<label>MT</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "1"){#' +
                                     '<label>SpeechRecognition</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "2"){#' +
                                     '<label>Transcriptionist</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "3"){#' +
                                     '<label>Review</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "4"){#' +
                                     '<label>SuperProof</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "5"){#' +
                                     '<label>PreAudit</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "6"){#' +
                                     '<label>Formatter</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "7"){#' +
                                     '<label>PostAudit</label>' +
                                     '#}else if(Level == "8"){#' +
                                     '<label>Customer</label>' +
                                     '#}else {#' +
                                     '<label>NA</label>' +
                                     '#}#',
                           title: "Level",

                       }
```

var levelType = function myfunction() {
            NA = 0,`enter code here`
            SpeechRecognition = 1,`enter code here`
            Transcriptionist = 2,
            Review = 3,
            SuperProof = 4,
            PreAudit = 5,
            Formatter = 6,
            PostAudit = 7,
            Customer = 8
        }